# Symbol prime when set XML variable with arabic language

Tags: xml, arabic, symbols

I want to set an XML variable in SQL Server. The XML data contains some arabic types in which sometimes are present symbol prime (''). This symbol is used to set the variable:

Example:

```
 DECLARE @xmlTest xml;
 SET @xmlTest = 
 N'<Text Width="62" TextAlign="Right">ח'נין</Text>
   <Text Width="20" TextAlign="Right">1</Text>'
```

In this case SQL consider the first part of set inside `''`, that means:

```
'<Text Width="62" TextAlign="Right">נין'
```

But I want to include all the text in the @xmlTest variable.
Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: This is hebrew, not arabic

Answer (score 0):

First, this is not Arabic, this is Hebrew.

Second, even Hebrew don't use `'` as a letter. so either the word is `חנין / khenin` and `'` is just a parasite. or `'` is mistaken for the letter yod `י`:

[image: Hebrew letter yod]

Comment: Yes you are right, it's hebrew. The problem is that I receive data from an hebrew server where they use ' instead of yod.